# How to add a link to a html page that is saved in the same folder than the principal html page?. I'm using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to add a link to a page named "Prueba_jQMobile", that is saved in a local folder with the others html page and jquery libraries. This is the code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
  <li><a href="#vacuna">Vacunas</a></li>                 <!-- is working well -->
  <li><a href="http://jquerymobile.com/">Test</a></li>   <!-- is working well -->
  <li><a href="Prueba_jQMobile.html">jQueryTest</a></li> <!-- isn't working -->
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Update: I executed the html page with firefox (before was using chrome) and the link was opened, but in plain text without the design. I'm going to continue testing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try : `<a href="Prueba_jQMobile.html" rel="external">JQueryTest</a>`

Answer (score 0):

So it doesn't open, when you click on the Link?

try:

```
<a href="./Prueba_jQMobile.html">jQueryTest</a>
```

Comment: Update: I executed the html page with firefox (before was using chrome) and the link was opened, but in plain text without the design. I'm going to continue testing it.

Comment: That sounds like an issue of your Prueba[...].html , but not of tee link to it

Comment: @Yaz - post your problem as a new question

Answer (score 0):

try `/Prueba_jQMobile.html` or if it's in a higher directory `../Prueba_jQMobile.html`

Answer (score -1):

Use the hash befor the URI.
It should be `<a href="#Prueba_jQMobile.html">jQueryTest</a>`